# Issues with -z / --time-cond Curl option over SFTP

Tags: curl, sftp

This is my first time using Curl.  I'm writing a script that automatically checks my SFTP server for updated/new images, and downloads any it finds.

The primary curl statement is:

```
curl -z 06-Nov-2018 -k -u $USER:$PASSW --remote-name-all sftp://$HOSTNAME/$PATH/image[1-9].jpg
```

My issue is that the -z /--time-cond flag does absolutely nothing.  This date should prevent it from downloading anything at all, and yet every file is downloaded.  I've tried dozens of dates, including -06-Nov-1994, to no avail. Does curl not support the -z option over SFTP, or am I doing something wrong?

I'm basing my date on the man page found [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/curl_getdate).  It says it's for curl 7.12.2+, I'm on 7.51.0 so that shouldn't be an issue.

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.51.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.51.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2j zlib/1.2.8 
libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.16.1 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 
pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 
Metalink
```

P.S. Does the -k option send my login info over plaintext? I'm assuming not since it's still SFTP, but I have absolutely no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I submitted an issue on the curl github page, and it turns out "There's no support for time conditional transfer with SFTP in curl."  Only HTTP and FTP.

https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1560

Oh well.  I'll see if I can implement it myself but honestly I'm in a time crunch and will probably just make a quick fix.